# How to replace multiple consecutive duplicate characters

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like this below.

```
aabbccddee
```

I want to replace the duplicate into one character in one line of RegEx to get the following result.

```
abcde
```

I can easily do this by doing

```
input_string = re.sub(ur"a+", u"a", input_string)
input_string = re.sub(ur"b+", u"b", input_string)
input_string = re.sub(ur"c+", u"c", input_string)
input_string = re.sub(ur"d+", u"d", input_string)
input_string = re.sub(ur"e+", u"e", input_string)
```

But this isn't as elegant as I want.

Comment: You can simply `''.join(set('aabbccddee'))`

Comment: or `re.sub(r'(.)\1+', r'\1', input)`

Comment: `''.join(set('aabbccddee'))` does not preserve order, I got `'acbed'` as output

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer.

```
input_string = re.sub(ur"([a-z])\1+", r"\1", input_string)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `groupby` from [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) *(almost copy/pasted from the doc)*:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> ''.join([k for k, g in groupby('aabbccddee')])
abcde
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this:

```
string = "aabbccddee"
print("".join(sorted(set(string), key = string.index)))
```

Output:

```
abcde
```

You could even use `OrderedDict` here:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
string = "aabbccddee"
print("".join(OrderedDict.fromkeys(string)))
```

Comment: This will stop to work when there are several sequence of the same character, for example: `'aabbccddeeaa'`

Comment: Is `aabbccddeeaa` still supposed to output `abcde`?

Comment: I don't think, more `abcdea` *(since the first `a`'s are not consecutive with the last `a`'s)*

Comment: hmmmmm yeah that's a good point. Yeah I thought it was supposed to remove duplicate strings and keep the order.